# Simple example of using Rails JSON with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm looking for a very very simple example where a Rails App does the following:

```
http://myapp.com/give_me_json
```

The returned data is a JSON:

```
[{"is_it_working":true, "very_simple_string":"Yes!"}]
```

I want to use the following function in JS to return the value of "is_it_working". But how???

```
function updateImpression(){

$.get('/give_me_json', function(data) {
    $('.da_place').html(data);
}
```

Instead this would return the whole json as a string.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the comment. I'm trying out each of the solutions to see which one I feel more confortable :)
I read the jQuery website about the json method, but it was not clear about how to access the key value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the response is `array` of `json object` so you need to get element from array 1st then property from json. **[SEE THE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ktLt8/)**

```
var response = [{"is_it_working":true, "very_simple_string":"Yes!"}];

//1 way
alert(response[0].is_it_working);

//2nd way
$(response).each(function(i,elem){
    alert(elem.is_it_working);
});
```

Comment: True, but see the answer by @Diode for the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it via `data.is_it_working` inside your `$.get()` method

Comment: -1 this is not correct, this wont work.. "data.is_it_working" is returning undefined. In this case the response is array of json. check my answer for more details.

Comment: Not if the mime type is wrong and the JS doesn't set the "json" dataType option for `$.get`.

Answer (score 1):

If content type is text

```
$.get('/give_me_json', function(data) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(data); // or eval(data)
    $('.da_place').html(response[0].is_it_working);
});
```

If content type is JSON

```
$.get('/give_me_json', function(data) {
    $('.da_place').html(data[0].is_it_working);
}, "json");
```

Or

```
$.getJSON('/give_me_json', function(data) {
    $('.da_place').html(data[0].is_it_working);
});
```

Comment: This is the problem. Try `console.log(data)` to see that you got a string back and not a parsed object since you omitted the "json" argument.

Answer (score 0):

would also need to specify 'json' in the get request so that jquery knows what do with what is returned